# Can I use floating point enums in Frege?

Tags: frege

I tried

```
println [1.0, 1.25..2.0]
```

but got

```
Double is not an instance of Enum
```

I couldn't find this issue in the "differences to Haskell", though.
Is there a recommended alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it should be in the "Differences".

For an alternative, consider

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

So, to get your list above, write:

```
takeWhile (<=2.0) (iterate (+0.25) 1)
```

It should also be possible to make `Double` and `Float` instances of `Enum`.
There is simply lots of work to do in the field of numeric types and type classes.

Comment: Thanks! 
I added the proposed solution to [real world frege](https://github.com/Dierk/Real_World_Frege/blob/master/chapter1/Lists.fr)